# How to hide item with qty 0 after shipment created

Tags: magento2, shipping, sales-order, backend

I just very curiously how magento can process this . Default when create shipment with set item qty to zero. It's will not visible in shipment
But i can't find file to process this
Can anyone show me the file or any snippets

Answer (score 0):

When you set 0 for some product and submit shipment, Post data will be something like:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [648] => 0
            [650] => 5
        )

    [comment_text] => 
)
```

Now open

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Order.php

And check the following method:

```
protected function _canShipItem($item, $qtys=array())
{
    if ($item->getIsVirtual() || $item->getLockedDoShip()) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->updateLocaleNumbers($qtys);

    if ($item->isDummy(true)) {
        if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
            if ($item->isShipSeparately()) {
                return true;
            }
            foreach ($item->getChildrenItems() as $child) {
                if ($child->getIsVirtual()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (empty($qtys)) {
                    if ($child->getQtyToShip() > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (isset($qtys[$child->getId()]) && $qtys[$child->getId()] > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else if($item->getParentItem()) {
            $parent = $item->getParentItem();
            if (empty($qtys)) {
                return $parent->getQtyToShip() > 0;
            } else {
                return isset($qtys[$parent->getId()]) && $qtys[$parent->getId()] > 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $item->getQtyToShip()>0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time but i can't find the code above in file mentioned. Your current magento version ?